# How to perform operations along a certain dimension of an array?

Tags: matlab, optimization, multidimensional-array, vectorization, slice

I have a 3D array containing five 3-by-4 slices, defined as follows:

```
rng(3372061);
M = randi(100,3,4,5);
```

I'd like to collect some statistics about the array:

- The maximum value in every column.
- The mean value in every row.
- The standard deviation within each slice.

This is quite straightforward using loops,

```
sz = size(M);
colMax = zeros(1,4,5);
rowMean = zeros(3,1,5);
sliceSTD = zeros(1,1,5);

for indS = 1:sz(3)
  sl = M(:,:,indS);
  sliceSTD(indS) = std(sl(1:sz(1)*sz(2)));
  for indC = 1:sz(1)
    rowMean(indC,1,indS) = mean(sl(indC,:));
  end

  for indR = 1:sz(2)
    colMax(1,indR,indS) = max(sl(:,indR));
  end  
end
```

But I'm not sure that this is the best way to approach the problem.

A common pattern I noticed in the documentation of [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) and [`std`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html) is that they allow to specify an additional `dim` input. For instance, in `max`:

> `M = max(A,[],dim)` returns the largest elements along dimension `dim`. For example, if `A` is a matrix, then `max(A,[],2)` is a column vector containing the maximum value of each row.

How can I use this syntax to simplify my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many functions in MATLAB allow the specification of a "dimension to operate over" when it matters for the result of the computation (several common examples are: `min`, `max`, `sum`, `prod`, `mean`, `std`, `size`, `median`, `prctile`, `bounds`) - which is especially important for multidimensional inputs. When the `dim` input is not specified, MATLAB has a way of choosing the dimension on its own, as explained in the documentation; for example in `max`:

> - If `A` is a vector, then `max(A)` returns the maximum of `A`.
> - If `A` is a matrix, then `max(A)` is a row vector containing the maximum value of each column.
> - If `A` is a multidimensional array, then `max(A)` operates along the first array dimension whose size does not equal `1`, treating the elements as vectors. The size of this dimension becomes `1` while the sizes of all other dimensions remain the same. If `A` is an empty array whose first dimension has zero length, then `max(A)` returns an empty array with the same size as `A`.

Then, using the `...,dim)` syntax we can rewrite the code as follows:

```
rng(3372061);
M = randi(100,3,4,5);

colMax = max(M,[],1);
rowMean = mean(M,2);
sliceSTD = std(reshape(M,1,[],5),0,2); % we use `reshape` to turn each slice into a vector
```

This has several advantages:

- The code is easier to understand.
- The code is potentially more robust, being able to handle inputs beyond those it was initially designed for.
- The code is likely faster.

In conclusion: it is always a good idea to read the documentation of functions you're using, and experiment with different syntaxes, so as not to miss similar opportunities to make your code more succinct.