# How to make the following loop code faster?

Tags: matlab, performance, loops, optimization, vectorization

I have the following code to calculate the semi-variance (dis-correlation) between scattered data points separated by a given distance in space (spatial lag) and in time (needs to be < 1, i.e., < 1 day). I need to calculate the semi-variance between a single data point and all of the other data points for each spatial lag.

However, it is very slow and I need to do this outside of a loop if possible. The second loop is relatively quick, it's the first loop, having to go through each element one-by-one, that is slow. Any ideas on how I can improve this code making it quicker? I use a datapoints array that is 90 times larger than the one used in this example.

I'm using MATLAB R2016a.

Working code:

```
N = 1E2; % example problem size
D = 1:N; % distance 
t = rand(1,N)+0.2; % time
datapoints = rand(1,N)+20; % temperature

% obtain differences between each element
distance_diff = abs(bsxfun(@minus, D.', D));
time_diff = abs(bsxfun(@minus, t.', t));

D_lag = [5 10 15 20 25]; % spatial lag, need to perform calculation for each lag

% the first loop is the one that slows down my function
for nn = 1:length(datapoints) % for each element
    for lag_n = 1:length(D_lag) % for each distance lag 
        sl = D_lag(lag_n);
        d = distance_diff(nn,:) < sl & time_diff(nn,:) < 1; % select points within spatial lag and 1 day
        strfile(nn,lag_n).variable = datapoints(d); % save selected data points

        % calculate semi-variogram for each nn element and each lag_n
        a = datapoints(nn)-strfile(nn,lag_n).variable; % for each element in data points
        strfile(nn,lag_n).semi_var = 0.5*((nanmean(a)^0.5)^4)/ ...
    (0.457+(0.494/length(strfile(nn,lag_n).variable)));
    end
end
```

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? This isn't technically "working code" since `spatial_vector_D` is undefined (but this entire `if` can be removed).

Comment: Yes, sorry. That bit of the code wasn't important at all. I have now removed so it should work now.

Comment: I am wondering whether I could use 'parfor' parallel computing, but there is a problem saving my values in the structure file.

Comment: I am using MATLAB R2016A

Comment: The very first thing you should do is heed MATLAB's warnings and stop increasing `strfile` in a loop. A benchmark (Run&Time) with `N=1E4` says that the line `strfile(nn,lag_n).variable = d...` alone takes up ~40% of the runtime. (I'm using R2018a)

Comment: how should I store the information instead? I use structure files all the time.

Comment: The problem is not using a structure, but increasing its size inside a loop. You can start by inverting the order of the iterations: `lag_n = numel(D_lag):-1:1` and `nn = numel(datapoints):-1:1`. Although these are just minor fixes, it does appears that this code can be vectorized nicely. BTW, is updating MATLAB an option for you? They introduced some optimizations for loops in the last few releases. BTW, it takes my not-so-new computer about 8s to run it with `N=1E4` with your loop definitions, but only 5s after inverting the order.

Comment: Thank you. I am now downloading and installing R2018a. Can you explain how I can vectorize this loop? I tried doing it before but I couldn't work out how to do it. I'll check out the loop optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to improve your code while keeping it in its current loop form, and it seems possible to get rid of the loops altogether. Since it would require a deeper understanding of your problem and the structure of your data, I will not show a vectorized version at this time (with the hope of adding it sometime in the future), but will try to explain how to get there.

I'll be using [implicit expansion syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20170325080933/http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/750/vectorization) (so no `bsxfun`) in this answer (works in R2016b onwards).

Here are the things I noticed immediately that can be improved in your solution:

1. MATLAB warns about growing `strfile` inside the inner loop. The easiest way to avoid it is to invert the loop order, then this:

   ```
   for nn = 1:length(datapoints) % for each element
     for lag_n = 1:length(D_lag) % for each distance lag
   ```

   turns into this:

   ```
   for nn = numel(datapoints):-1:1 % for each element
     for lag_n = numel(D_lag):-1:1 % for each distance lag
   ```

   (I'm using the `numel` function as it is [more expressive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170519212339/http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/973/common-mistakes-and-errors) than `length`)
2. Since you only ever check if the time difference is smaller than a single value (`1`), you absolutely don't need to do it inside the inner loop. In fact, you can even move it outside the loops entirely, so instead of:

   ```
   for nn = ...
     for lag_n = ...
       sl = D_lag(lag_n);    
       d = distance_diff(nn,:) < sl & time_diff(nn,:) < 1;
   ```

   You can do this:

   ```
   td = time_diff < 1; % or even directly: td = abs(t.'-t) < 1
   for nn = ...
     ttd = td(nn,:); % doesn't change each lag_n, no need to recompute
     for lag_n = ...
       d = distance_diff(nn,:) < D_lag(lag_n) & ttd;
   ```

   The above is the first step towards vectorization. In vectorization, you want to work in a "[SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)" approach, that is, issue a command once and let it work on as large a chunk of data as possible, ideally your entire dataset at once.

The above two changes are a result of a careful consideration of memory allocation and data dependencies, and yield about a 50% reduction in runtime.

Now, as promised, few pointers regarding vectorization:

- If we convert `D_lag` into a vector along the 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension, we could compute all required values of `d` in one go:

  ```
  d = distance_diff < permute(D_lag,[1,3,2]) & time_diff < 1; % ...or simply
  d = abs(D.'-D) < permute(D_lag,[1,3,2]) & abs(t.'-t) < 1;
  ```
- Instead of `length`, you would use `size(strfile(...),#)`.
- Instead of `nanmean(x)` you would use the multi-argument syntax as discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49510413/3372061).
- I think it would make sense to create the `struct` output after all computations are complete, using:

  ```
  strfile = struct('variable', (...), 'semi_var',(...) );
  ```

---

Here's my code in case anybody wants to benchmark or build upon it:

```
function q49779404
N = 1E4; % example problem size
D = 1:N; % distance
t = rand(1,N)+0.2; % time
datapoints = rand(1,N)+20; % temperature

% obtain differences between each element
distance_diff = abs(D.'-D); % implicit expansion
time_diff = abs(t.'-t); % implicit expansion

D_lag = [5 10 15 20 25]; % spatial lag, need to perform calculation for each lag
out{1} = method1(datapoints, D_lag, distance_diff, time_diff);
out{2} = method2(datapoints, D_lag, distance_diff, time_diff);
% out{3} = method3(datapoints, D_lag, distance_diff, time_diff);

function strfile = method1(datapoints, D_lag, distance_diff, time_diff)
for nn = 1:length(datapoints) % for each element
  for lag_n = 1:length(D_lag) % for each distance lag    
    sl = D_lag(lag_n);    
    d = distance_diff(nn,:) < sl & time_diff(nn,:) < 1; % select points within spatial lag and 1 day        
    strfile(nn,lag_n).variable = datapoints(d); % save selected data points

    % calculate semi-variogram for each nn element and each lag_n
    a = datapoints(nn)-strfile(nn,lag_n).variable; % for each element in data points
    strfile(nn,lag_n).semi_var = 0.5*((nanmean(a)^0.5)^4) / ...
      (0.457+(0.494/length(strfile(nn,lag_n).variable)));    
  end
end

function strfile = method2(datapoints, D_lag, distance_diff, time_diff)
td = time_diff < 1; 
for nn = numel(datapoints):-1:1 % for each element
  ttd = td(nn,:); % doesn't change each lag_n, no need to recompute
  for lag_n = numel(D_lag):-1:1 % for each distance lag    
    d = distance_diff(nn,:) < D_lag(lag_n) & ttd; % select points within spatial lag and 1 day        
    strfile(nn,lag_n).variable = datapoints(d); % save selected data points

    % calculate semi-variogram for each nn element and each lag_n
    a = datapoints(nn)-strfile(nn,lag_n).variable; % for each element in data points
    strfile(nn,lag_n).semi_var = 0.5*((nanmean(a).^0.5).^4) ./ ...
      (0.457+(0.494./length(strfile(nn,lag_n).variable)));    
  end
end

function strfile = method3(datapoints, D_lag, distance_diff, time_diff)
d = distance_diff < permute(D_lag,[1,3,2]) & time_diff < 1;
strfile = struct('variable',[],'semi_var',[]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! very informative response. Altering my function using these methods and real data is now 60% faster than it was previously.